# Telnet, Connection To Hotmail & Gmail Fails

Tags: php, email, smtp, telnet

I want to validate email addresses for existance without sending a confirmation email.
I have found [this tutorial](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/).

The method covered in the tutorial doesn't work for me when I try to validate popular domains like hotmail.com, gmail.com, yahoo.com, etc.

[image: screenshot 1 gmail.com domain]

Surprisingly, I am able to connect to an email which includes a special domain (something like `someone@someone.me`).

How can I connect to domains like hotmail.com, gmail.com etc. via telnet? Which port number should I use?

Comment: That depends on the server, and I will bet that most of them don't have telnet enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Port 25 is the standard SMTP port for server to server communication and is what you want to use.

Port 587 is often used for new message submission from local subscribers, and therefore (generally) requires authentication before use, so is not generally useful for what you're trying to do.

Please note however, that this technique should not be considered definitive. At best, it's a hint. For example, some mail servers will accept (or at least, pretend to accept) every message, regardless of recipient, in order to avoid this exact sort of targeting:

```
% telnet mta5.am0.yahoodns.net 25
Trying 98.138.112.38...
Connected to mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mta1057.mail.ne1.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
HELO foo.com
250 mta1057.mail.ne1.yahoo.com
MAIL FROM: <foo@bar.com>
250 sender <foo@bar.com> ok
RCPT TO: <this_can_not_possibly_exist_sdfjghdfkgsdfgsdfgdf@yahoo.com>
250 recipient <this_can_not_possibly_exist_sdfjghdfkgsdfgsdfgdf@yahoo.com> ok
QUIT
221 mta1057.mail.ne1.yahoo.com
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If you're taking email messages as part of a registration process and you want to ensure that they're valid, you're better off simply making the reception of a welcome message a requirement for the process, by including a "click here to activate your account" link. If you're doing mass mailing, use a service like MailChimp or ConstantContact, and they'll monitor failures for you. If you're sending one-off notifications, use a service like MailGun to catch bounces.

Comment: thank you for your answer but that didn't do it. also, alternative ways (like confirmation email) are not a choice for this project. thanks anyway

Comment: "but that didn't do it" But what didn't do what?

Comment: i tried port number 25 and still got the same error in the ss.

Comment: Works fine for me. Your outgoing connection is probably firewalled.

Comment: if you mean i should try whilr firewall is off, i have tried but got no difference in results. If not, could you lease explain? tia

Comment: It's likely not the firewall on your local Windows machine, but the firewall on your Internet gateway.